# how to add file attachment in PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer for mailing facility, I want add  file with each mail from my server.

following is folder structure on my server.

```
-public-html
  - main-folder
    - files
       - a.doc
       - b.docx
    - mailer
       - mailer.php
```

i have tried the following line in my mailer.php file but it is not working

```
$mail->AddAttachment('main-folder/files/a.doc', 'pricelist.doc');
```

Comment: What happens when you use the absolute path to the file?

Comment: i have not try that, let me try that, thanks for reply

Comment: not working using absolute path also, mail sent successfully with all content, but only attachment is missing, you can up-vote this question, so i can get quick answer

Comment: Did you check the file permissions?

Comment: its 644 for a.doc and 755 for "files" folder, tried by giving 777 to a.doc, but not working

Comment: Are any error messages setting set?  Can you check ErrorInfo after calling AddAttachment

Comment: no error, it working fine, but only attachment is missing, but what line should i write after `$mail->AddAttachment('main-folder/files/a.doc', 'pricelist.doc'); ` for error checking

Comment: Try, 

`$mail->AddAttachment('main-folder/files/a.doc', 'pricelist.doc');
if($mail->IsError()) die($mail->ErrorInfo);`

Comment: yes its gives following error `Could not access file: main-folder/files/a.doc`

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the path.

I re-look at changing the paths to absolute.  e.g `/var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/public-html/main-folder/files/a.doc`

Comment: still no luck dear, same error

Comment: If safe mode is on, main-folder/files/a.doc has to be with the DocumentRoot. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/main-folder/files/a.doc', 'pricelist.doc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path was wrong, for the record. you needed to be giving the string '../files/a.doc' instead, based on the file layout you gave in the question. IT was not PHPMailer requiring a full absolute path to the file.